# jquery hide div, show another, on click

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I found some jQuery to help me with showing and hiding a `div` display. What's supposed to happen is that when one link is clicked, it hides the first `div` and shows the second. I found several ways to do this but it breaks the whole page only showing the footer and nothing else on the page every time. It looks really weird, but i don't know enough about jQuery to fix it so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').eq($(this).index()).show();
    $('div').not($('div').eq($(this).index())).hide();
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>link1</a>
<a href='#'>link2</a>
<a href='#'>link3</a>

<div> div for link 1</div>
<div class="hide"> div for link 2</div>
<div class="hide"> div for link 3</div>
```

http://www.embroiderywear.com/designshirtsonline1.html
Here's the test page so you can see how it's messing up (or the solution if it gets fixed) I'm using foundation 5 for the frame work so i'm not sure if it's something there that's breaking it or something else.

Comment: Are you using PHP for rendering Divs?

Comment: no i'm using html - at hmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tushar already mentioned, you need to make a Container that will wrap all of your divs and then you can play with your Javascript/JQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<a href='#'>link1</a>
<a href='#'>link2</a>
<a href='#'>link3</a>

<div id="divContainer">
    <div> div for link 1</div>
    <div class="hide"> div for link 2</div>
    <div class="hide"> div for link 3</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#divContainer div').hide();
    $('div#divContainer div').eq($(this).index()).show();
  });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/boq0c76f/

Answer (score 1):

`$('div')` will select all the `<div>` elements on the page.

You can

1. wrap the `div` elements of interest in a container

   ```
   <div id="container">
       <div> div for link 1</div>
       <div class="hide"> div for link 2</div>
       <div class="hide"> div for link 3</div>
   </div>
   ```

   And in JavaScript, use

   ```
   $('#container div').eq($(this).index()).show()  // Show the corr. el
       .siblings().hide();                         // Hide other
   ```
2. add a common & unique class on all the `div` elements of interest

   ```
   <div class="myClass"> div for link 1</div>
   <div class="hide myClass"> div for link 2</div>
   <div class="hide myClass"> div for link 3</div>
   ```

   and in JavaScript

   ```
   $('.myClass').eq($(this).index()).show()
       .siblings().hide();
   ```

and use the selector to select only those elements.

Comment: i tried this using just $('#templatesbox .inspiration').eq($(this).index()).show()
    .siblings().hide(); as the script but it didn't work and i added the classes and id

Comment: @Felicyia Can you add live demo on jsfiddle.net and share link here

Comment: @Felicyia You've to wrap the code in click handler on anchors. Here's updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/yu87wzw7/1/